# Finding number of connected components in an undirected graph

Tags: c++, graph, depth-first-search, connected-components

The users inputs the number of vertices (*n*) and then - in the next *n* lines - how the vertices are connected, namely that the number *x* in *i*-th line means that vertex *i* is connected with vertex *x* (the graph is undirected). The task is to find the number of connected components in this graph, and my code - for some reason I'm not able to find - outputs wrong values (for example, with input *4 2 1 2 4*, my code outputs *4* instead of *2*). Any help greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>

int n;

using namespace std;
vector <int> graph[1000006];
int components[1000006];
int no_of_components;
stack <int> mystack;

int main(){

    cin >> n;

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        int X;
        cin >> X;
        graph[X-1].push_back(i);
    }

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){

        if (components[i]>0) continue;

        no_of_components++;

        mystack.push(i);
        components[i]=no_of_components;

        while (mystack.empty()==false){
            int v;

            v=mystack.top();
            mystack.pop();

            for (int u=0; u<graph[v].size(); u++){
                if (components[u]>0) continue;

                mystack.push(u);
                components[u]=no_of_components;

            }
        }
    }

    cout << no_of_components;

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code there is a confusion between the counter `u` which allows you to iterate through the connections of the node v, and the connections themselves:

- `v` is a node
- `graph[v]` is the vector of connections
- `u` is an index in in the vector of connections
- so `graph[v][u]` is the node connected to `v` and `component[graph[v][u]]` the component marker you have to update

So you have to correct the inner for-loop as follows:

```
        for (int u=0; u<graph[v].size(); u++){
            if (components[graph[v][u]]>0) continue;

            mystack.push(graph[v][u]);
            components[graph[v][u]]=no_of_components;

        }
```

Then works as expected.

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/cAZKKP)

Comment: @hetajr To avoid any doubts, I have updated the online demo to display the graph and show the groupings identified with the corrected version of the algorithm.